# Installation profile missing after upgrade to 8.6.1

Tags: 8, upgrading, installation-profiles

I did an upgrade from Drupal 8.5.6 to 8.6.1 and the installation (minimal) profile broke. I noticed that the minimal.install file was removed from the installation profile. I assume this is related to how the install profiles and dependances are changing in 8.6.x -- but this upgrade completely breaks a whole lot of things.

Anyone else have an idea on how to restore the install profile?

I am still digging around to see why this file was removed but any insight would be awesome.

Comment: That file was removed in [#2914379] which was committed 9 month ago and already didn't exist in Drupal 8.5. You didn't explain what problems you are seeing but it's not related to that. Note that install profiles without an install hook can install from configuration, so maybe that's what's causing problems for you. You need to explain what those are though

Comment: I am getting a bunch of errors when attempting to edit Views, view the user list, etc. It appears random but the error is the same:

Drupal\Core\Extension\Exception\UnknownExtensionException: The module minimal does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList->get() (line 257 of /core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ExtensionList.php).

Sorry, I forgot to paste in the error I was seeing.

Comment: Also, the upgrade went smoothly. There were no errors or any obvious problems.

I suppose my issue is how do I reconnect the install profile to the site.

Comment: If you have steps on how to reproduce the problem then I'd suggest you open a core issue, I don't think it's something someone can "answer away" here.

Comment: I created an issue as a support request since I can't replicate what happened. I can only guess at this point since the upgrade appeared to go fine: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3000677

Comment: Ah, hah. I see what has happened. I was looking at the repository and I see that the file was still present after the 8.6.x upgrade. I am not sure how the file was still present but I use Acquia Dev Desktop to do local builds before deploying. I wonder if the upgrade from Drupal 6 somehow flubbed. Replacing the file with a copy fixes the issue. Now I need to figure how how to remedy this in future updates.